# Maximum number of candidate keys may have

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

I am having troubles when I trying to solve this question. Can someone help me?

Consider the relation schema R=(A, B, C, D) with an unknown set of functional dependencies: What is the maximum number of (candidate) keys that R may have? Design a set of functional dependencies on R to achieve the maximum number of (candidate) keys.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what you are able to do here & say what things you have been taught are relevant. What about sompler cases? How did the many similar SO questions you looked at help? Right now you are just asking us to rewrite your textbook from scratch with a bespoke tutorial & do your homework. PS PLease ask one question per question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding largest number of candidate keys that a relation has?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41107632/3404097)